# What is the purpose of a SMTP VRFY Scanner?

Tags: windows, smtp, scanning

I need some assistance with these type of scanners, there seem to be many of them on the web but I can't seem to find specific details of what they are meant to achieve.

I understand that they are communicating on the SMTP port, but I am not certain of what type of information they are trying to get.

The reason I ask this is because I am currently investigating a SMTP VRFY Scanner. I have made the scanner to connect to a windows xp system but it states

```
Waiting for SMTP banner
220 testing221 Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.2600.2180 ready at  Sun, 27 Sep 2015 19:04:44 +0100
```

`testing221` corresponds to the domain on the SMTP virtual server, on the xp system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SMTP VRFY command is intended to allow a sender to verify the correctness of an email address without actually sending an email.

This feature was abused by spammers very early on.  As a result, most SMTP servers are configured to ignore the command.

They are effectively useless for the public internet these days.  You will find very few, if any, domains configured to support the command.

Comment: Would I be right to assume that it is possible to retrieve all the email addresses from a system that is still vulnerable? e.g. the xp system I am testing this with?

Comment: Only by probing all possible email addresses for that domain in a loop.  That would probably be detected as an intrusion attempt by many modern systems (intrusion detection systems watching for suspicious access patterns).  If you try this against Google for example, your IP will almost certainly be blacklisted before you get far.

Comment: I understand how an IDS functions but I am just curious of how this will work on a LAN with no security features and using an outdated OS. From what I can understand is that this is simply a brute force program looking for possible usernames to match with the domain, would that be right?

Comment: The actual behavior depends on the specific mail server, see http://cr.yp.to/smtp/vrfy.html